# python|django how to post file, change it, and send it back?

Tags: python, django, request

I am writing a small test project with python\django.

I'm sending an image to server (with request post), resizing it and want it back to the client.

So far it seems that everything working properly beside that i dont know how to send the file back to the client.

CLIENT:

```
testFile = "<location>"
api_url = 'http://localhost:9999/upload'
files = {'file': open(testFile, 'rb')}
r = requests.post(api_url,files=files,data={"m":10,"n":15})
files["file"].close()
print r -> status 200
```

SERVER:
@csrf_exempt
def post(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    logger.info("New post request")
    #logger.info(request.FILES)
    file = request.FILES['file']
    resized_frame = job_manager.add_job(file,request.POST.get("m"),request.POST.get("n"))
    logger.info("returning new resized frame ")
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='image/png') 
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % smart_str(resized_frame)
    return response
    #return HttpResponse(resized_frame)
else:
    return HttpResponse('500')
```

can I even send response with files while getting a post request?

Comment: In my experience when you want the client to get the image as a file you'll have to write the image's data to the response's output stream, but I'm not sure how to do this in python.

Comment: Like Nicolás said, you are setting the `content_type` and `Content-Disposition`, but you need to write the actual content of the file to the response. It's unclear exactly how, because you have that `job_manager` that is presumably asynchronous, but you should have to check when the job is done, get the content and write it to the response.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida ,
job_manager is the one who getting the original frame and resizing it.

When he is finished he return the new resized frame, and i do see it.
What I'm not sure is how to attache it to the response, and how to see it in the client.